# git rm file name with space

Tags: git

I tried merging with the command line for a project in Xcode and I think a file needs to be removed.  It is a file that exists in the branch I was merging from, but not the branch I was merging into.  The problem is it has a space in the name:

```
TestService/TestService copy-Info.plist
```

How do I remove that file?  thanks!

Comment: Have you tried quoting it in single or double quotes?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The same way you'd use `rm` to remove such a file: quote the name:

```
git rm "TestService/TestService copy-Info.plist"
```

or

```
git rm 'TestService/TestService copy-Info.plist'
```

or

```
git rm TestService/TestService\ copy-Info.plist
```

Depending on your shell and the names of other files, tab completion may help with this.  Typing

`$ git rm Te`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

will likely complete the directory name:

`$ git rm TestingService/`

Then typing part of the file name and another tab:

`$ git rm TestService/Te`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

will complete the filename, including an inserted `\` to escape the space character:

`$ git rm TestService/TestService\ copy-Info.plist`

But tab completion usually only expands a unique prefix based on all the files available, so this may or may not work.

Comment: It seems not work on [git version 2.15.1] with command like git  rm --cached [file path]

Comment: @DanyunLiu I just saw comment. How does it not work?

Answer (score 5):

You can either quote the filename:

```
git rm "TestService/TestService copy-Info.plist"
```

Or escape the space:

```
git rm TestService/TestService\ copy-Info.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

Have your tried to add quotes to the filename? `"TestService/TestService copy-Info.plist"` I'm not 100% sure how it works with Git.

Answer (score 2):

If you use  Ubuntu sometimes you need to use `git rm --cached -r "TestService/TestService copy-Info.plist"`