# Delete a file from a Git repo with an apostrophe or quote in the name

Tags: git, filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git rm file name with space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855517/git-rm-file-name-with-space)

I have a Git repository and I'm trying to delete a file but it has a single quote (or apostrophe) (`'`) in the filename.

For example, `git'hub.txt`

Each time I try to delete the file I type:

```
git rm git'hub.txt
```

it goes

```
git rm git'hub.txt

>
```

waiting until I end it with another `'`.

Is there a way to delete this file without it doing that?

Comment: What happens if you put a \ just before the quote?

Comment: This is standard shell escaping: `"git'hub.txt"`, `'git\'hub.txt'`, and `git\'hub.txt` will work in sh standard dialects.

Comment: Found it out, i had to do 'git\'hub.txt'. To the file name. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What differs from "[git rm file name with space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855517/git-rm-file-name-with-space)" is that, this time, the special character is a simple quote.

A simple quotes are also called **[strong quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11429466/6309)**: they prevent characters from having special meanings... except from the single quote itself.

That is why you need to escape that one.

```
git rm 'git\'hub.txt'
```

If the special character had been a space, no escape would have been needed:

```
git rm 'git hub.txt'
```