# git bash escaping brackets - Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-bash

I have copied a temp page over to my staging area and I cannot remove it.

**bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('**

src/app/components/hotels/hotelsFactory (copy).js

I have tried all escaping using backslash but connot seem to remove it:

rm src/app/components/hotels/hotelsFactory (another copy).js

Comment: Why am I voted down on something that I clearly don't know and that someone has understood and I have followed their directions and solved the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to quote the name. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11855549/2343305).

In your case will be:

```
git rm "src/app/components/hotels/hotelsFactory (another copy)".js
```